# How to make UITableView scroll show on more than 25 records?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have created an iOS app with UITableView.UITableView by default loads 25 records. I am scrolling the tableview to get another 25 records.

How do I get another set of data?

Here is my code.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return timeList.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Item";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
              UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    NSDictionary *tmpDict = [timeList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSMutableString *text;
     NSString *currentstatus;
    text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpDict objectForKeyedSubscript:startdate]];
    currentstatus = [self statusString:[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpDict objectForKeyedSubscript:status]]];
    NSMutableString *detail;
    detail = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"User:%@ , Hours:%@ , Status: %@ ",
              [tmpDict objectForKey:username], [tmpDict objectForKey:hours], currentstatus];
    cell.textLabel.text = text;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text= detail;
     cell.accessoryType =UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSDictionary *tmpDict = [timeList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSString * storyboardName=@"Main";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
    EditViewController *evc =[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EditViewController"];
       evc.startday =[NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpDict objectForKeyedSubscript:startdate]];
    evc.user_id = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tmpDict objectForKeyedSubscript:user_id]];
    evc.tab =@"wktime";
    [self presentViewController:evc animated:NO completion:Nil];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First you have check whether the tableview reached last cell or not. If it is reached then again you have to reload the next set of data.

Use the below code to check whether the tableview reached last cell or not.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell (UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row == timeList.count-1)
    {
        //Your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use delegate method of UISCrollView `scrollViewDidEndScrolling` to load more data and then you can refresh your tableView.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a simple way. by adding below code in cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate method.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  if (indexPath.row ==  timeList.count-1) {
     NSLog(@"load more");
   }
  .....
  return cell;
 }
```

if condition will be executed at the end of tableview, there you can add your logic to load more data's.